# How to write junit for ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor in Java?

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, threadpoolexecutor

I have a Java class which is using ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor to run a job.I have tried to write junit test with mockto. But its not calling runnable run method.

Example:

```
class MyExecutor {
  ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor stp = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor();

  pubilc void start() {// how to write test junit 
    stp.scheduleAtFixedRate(executeRunnable(), 2,2, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
  }
  private void executeRunnable() {
  new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       System.out.println("running");
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Junit

```
class MyExecutorTest {
    
    public void testStart() {
    MyExecutor exec = new MyExecutor();
    exec.start();//its not printing from run method
    }
}
```

Comment: As a more meta-question ... why would you want to test the ``ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`` class? Would you not assume it has been tested by the authors, etc? You would just need to test your own code as executed by the scheduler.

Comment: I just need to test the start functionality  which is called with run method?

Comment: yes, you should be testing what your run method does as that is the 'business logic' of interest and the code you are writing. The scheduling of it is essentially boilerplate code handled by a 3rd party library you did not write.

Comment: But as junit functionality,  it should call . why its not calling

Comment: that's harder to say without seeing more of the code. Does the test execute and complete before the scheduler gets a chance to run the Runnable object?

Comment: Yes. its executing without calling run method. Let me share junit code. have added junit

Comment: ``exec.start()`` tells the scheduler to run, and your config tells it to run after an initial delay of 2 (seconds?). But ... your code will not hang around to wait for the scheduler to run after 2 seconds unless you tell it to. The code from @daniu looks like it is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provide the executor from the outside then `verify`.

```
class MyClass {
  private final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor stp;
  public MyClass(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor ex) { stp = ex; }

  public void start() {
    stp.scheduleAtFixedRate(executeRunnable(), 2,2, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
  }
}

class MyTest {
  @Mock
  ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor exec;

  public void testStart() {
    MyClass sut = new MyClass(exec);
    sut.start();
    verify(exec).scheduleAtFixedRate(any(), eq(2), eq(2), eq(TimeUnit.SECONDS));
  }
}
```

This way you make sure the class schedules a runnable at the expected time. If you want to ensure the behavior of the runnable, you can use an `ArgumentCaptor`, but I don't see how you would verify a `System.out.println()`.